# python script doesn't output to terminal

Tags: python, macos, zsh

I am running a simple Python program hello_world.py on zsh on Mac: `print("Hello Python world!")`

When running in zsh terminal - nothing happens (see attached image), whereas I am expecting a result: Hello Python world!

If I load up Python interpreter with python3, and run `print("Hello Python world!")`, it works completely fine and outputs: Hello Python world!
Essentially, the output to terminal is not working by some reason.

Any help?

[image: see last command without output to the terminal]

Comment: What is the content of `hello_world.py`? What is the output when you run `cat hello_world.py` on terminal?

Comment: Could you please add the contents of the script to the question? Just for more information.

Comment: @ywbaek Nothing gets displayed when I run "cat hello_world.py"; simply next terminal prompt is generated. The content of hello_world.py is "print("Hello Python world!")". But regardless of content, there is nothing displayed in zsh terminal. Clearly it has something to do with terminal itself. Python code is fine.

Comment: @simic0de The content is added in the question itself in the first paragraph: "print("Hello Python world!")". The issue is with terminal display, not Python code. Thank you

Comment: @CONvid19 Any suggestions?

Comment: @NikolaySitnikov If you don't see the output from running `cat hello_world.py`, it means the file is empty. There is nothing wrong with your terminal. You are just running an empty file. That's why there is no output.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The issue is not with Python code. I can't get the output of any script display in my zsh terminal window.

Comment: @ywbaek You are right! Sorry to bother

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you type more hello_world.py to ensure you haven't overwritten the code. Next, you should run python3 from the terminal and type in the one line from the file to be sure it works. Then try python3 hello_world.py. If it still doesn't print I'd start a new terminal window and try again.